# Trouble understanding noncrossing partitions

Tags: integer-partitions, catalan-numbers

I am trying to understand what a non-crossing partition means.

I was reading a paper and it states A partition is noncrossing if there do not exist four distinct elements $$a < b < c < d$$ with
$a, c$ both in one block and $b, d$ both in another. This doesn't make any sense to me, So I mean I want simpler explanation of what noncrossing partitions means with examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the elements of your set in clockwise order around a circle. Connect elements that belong to the same block by a straight line. A partition is non-crossing if and only if the lines don't cross.